# SQLalchemy +Postgresql accessing Array of jsonb elements

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query that looks like this.
`query = db.query(status_cte.c.finding_status_history)`
the finding_status_history column is of type array when I check its `.type`. It's an array of `jsonb` objects I can easily change it to be `json` instead if it's easier. I've also tested this out with it as `json`.

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "status": "closed",
                "created_at": "2023-01-27T18:05:27.579817",
                "previous_status": "open"
            },
            {
                "status": "open",
                "created_at": "2023-01-27T18:05:28.694352",
                "previous_status": "closed"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I'm trying to access the first dictionary nested inside `data` and access the `status` column.

I've tried to grab it using `query = db.query(status_cte.c.finding_status_history[0])` but this returns a list of empty dictionaries like so.

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

I'm not sure why that doesn't work as its my impression that i should grab the first entry. I'm assuming i need to access "data" some how first but i've also tried...

`query = db.query(status_cte.c.finding_status_history.op('->>')('data')`
Which gives me `jsonb[] ->> unknown operator doesn't exist`. I've tried to type cast data to be that of String and i get the same error but `jsonb[] ->> String` etc etc

Also when looping through the items `for item in query.all()` i'm seeing that [0] results in `(None,)` and [1] results in

```
({
                "status": "closed",
                "created_at": "2023-01-27T18:05:27.579817",
                "previous_status": "open"
},)
```

as a tuple...

Answer (score 0):

The secret was that [0] is not the first element. [1] is also noted that [-1] doesn't appear to give me the last element so i also had to order my aggregated json objects.